# Porque há dois uses no delphi

Tags: delphi

Porque há duas `uses` nas units do Delphi ?

Um logo abaixo de `interface` e outro logo em `implementation`, qual a finalidade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que quanto mais enxuta for os uses na Interface, melhor.

Isso porque você vai poder deixar mais explicito o que a sua interface realmente precisa, e o que seu código vai implementar

As classes definidas nos uses formam uma ligação entre as units onde elas dizem o que elas podem fazer. Basicamente é por onde elas se comunicam.

Na interface você diz o que elas podem fazer.

Já a implementação é onde você diz o que precisa fazer.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, encontrei este link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125641/differences-in-uses-clause

Answer (score 4):

A de cima para usar recursos do sistema e componentes,
tais como: `System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB` etc, etc.

A de baixo serve para usar recursos de outra `Units` como: `ufuncoes`, `uTelaInicial` etc etc.

O padrão é assim, mas nada impede de você usar as uses de baixo lá em cima ou vice versa! Mas... nem tudo são flores, pode dar erro de compilação tanto de execução, então, por padrão, use a de cima para Declarações de uses do Sistema e Componentes, e de baixo para uses de `Units` do seu projeto!

**Lembrando que declarar em cima e em baixo a mesma uses causara um erro de Declaração Duplicada!**

Comment: Eu discordo um pouco da sua afirmação.
Não necessariamente o uses da `interface` é para recursos do sistemas e componentes.
Até porque se eu tiver uma classe simples, onde seja preciso fazer um `StrToInt`, eu não vou precisar dar uses do `SysUtils` na `interface`. 
E outra, eu posso ter um método onde o retorno é um Objeto especifico, nesse caso teria que declarar minha classe na `Interface` para poder usa-lo

Comment: Você pode discordar "Achando"  que afirmei! Pois, basta abrir um simples projeto e adicionar componentes que usam recursos do sistema, como um DBGrid ou outros, a declaração automática será na Interface. E ao usar Alt+F11 será adicionado na Implementation, O Padrão que "Afirmei" é este!

Comment: Vou criar um `record helper` de String, onde vou implementar 2 métodos, `SaveToFile` e `LoadFromFile`.
Para isso vou usar `TStringStream`.
Não há necessidade de declarar `System.Classes` e `System.SysUtils` na Interface

Answer (score -3):

Apenas organização. A primeira lá no início é para bibliotecas do Delphi que o projeto precisa. A segunda é para as unidades dos arquivos do seu projeto, Unit de um form por exemplo.

Se você usar só a primeira via funcionar da mesma forma.

Em resumo a primeira para Units do Delphi a segunda para as suas Units.

Ok. Espero ter ajudado.